# Tap value increase and decrease for individual item in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

Can anyone help how can increase and decrease the tap value for individual item?
Here is my code:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of product; let i = index">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img src= "{{ item.product_image }}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>{{ item.product_name}}</h2><br>
    <p> {{ item.product_desc}}</p>



    <button  item-end ion-button small (tap)="tapEventsub(i)">-</button>
    <p item-end> {{tap}} </p>
    <button  item-end ion-button small (tap)="tapEventadd(i)">+</button>

    <button ion-button  item-end small round>Add</button>
  </ion-item>
```

.ts file code is

```
tapEventadd(index:number) {
    this.tap++;
}

tapEventsub(index:number) {
    if (this.tap>0) {
        this.tap--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you are using the same variable for every item. Firstly you should have a seperate tap property for every item.

Comment: you should use a separate property(ex: item.quantity) and on click pass that item as parameter and then update the quantity accordingly. use item.quantity to display individual tap count

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to declare the `tap` variable as an array instead, and then use the index to increment or decrement the value at that index:

```
tap: Array<number>; //declare the tap variable as an array instead
...

tapEventadd(index:number) {
    this.tap[index]++;
}

tapEventsub(index:number) {
    if (this.tap[index]>0) {
        this.tap[index]--;
}
```

In your template, change the tap variable to pass in the index:

```
<p item-end> {{tap[i]}} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .html file, you could have your method tapEventadd() take in your item.name as the parameter. Example:

```
tapEventadd(item.product_name)
```

and in your ts file you loop through the array and if the names are equal, you increase or decrease the product quantity.

Example:

```
tapEventadd(item){
for(var i=0;i<this.tap.length;i++) {
  var product = this.tap[i];
  if(product.name==item) {
    product.quantity++;
  }
}
```

}

Hope it helps! :)